# Strange behavior in deleting core data contents

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I use the following code to delete the coredata DB contents... I get the notification properly..But it seems the data are not deleted... I can't figure it out...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
       NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
       [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
       NSError *errors;
       NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errors];
       NSLog(@"FinalArray:%@",[finalArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex]);
       NSManagedObject *managedObject=[finalArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];
       NSLog(@"NSManagedObject:%@",managedObject);
       for (int i=0;i<[items count];i++)
       {
           if ([managedObject isEqual:[items objectAtIndex:i]])
           {
               [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
               NSLog(@"gone");
           }
       }
       NSNotificationCenter *nc=[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
       [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(deleteCheck:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
       NSLog(@"dffsdf%@",[errors description]);
       if (self.managedObjectContext==nil)
       {
           NSLog(@"deleted");
       }
```

Notification Func call

```
  - (void)deleteCheck:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSLog(@"CoreData got Deleted");
    NSDictionary *userInfoDictionary = [notification userInfo];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [userInfoDictionary objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSLog(@"DeletedObjects%@",deletedObjects);
}
```

Since NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification called for each time when I tap the delete button... But no effects in DB... Suggestions Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save at the end.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple delete method that i use, its work perfect  :

```
-(void)deleteRecords{
NSFetchRequest * deleteRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[deleteRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"yourTabelName" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[deleteRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * cars = [context executeFetchRequest:deleteRequest error:&error];

if ([cars count] !=0) {      

    //error handling goes here

    for (NSManagedObject * car in cars) {

        [context deleteObject:car];
    }
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [context save:&saveError];
    //   [tableView reloadData];


}
else {
   NSLog(@"No Data To delete");

} }
```

Comment: This will completely delete all your contents in ur entity... I don't want this I wanna delete the particular content which the user selects.. Well thanks for ur response too...